# Tomcat times out when attempt to start in debug mode using STS

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've been having issues starting debug mode in STS since this morning, but cant' seem to trace the reason or the cause as to what's causing this sudden change in behaviour. When I click on the debug icon in eclipse/STS, the following occurs

A tab that says "jdbcOdbcDriver.finalize() line: not available is loaded
The server times out after 45 seconds.

The console gives me this long log as well, but I'm not seeing any errors occurring within it.

```
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;.
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:clearbox' did not find a matching property.
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1753 ms
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\chris@empatico.ca\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.1.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\clearbox\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\chris@empatico.ca\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.1.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\clearbox\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-el-7.0.52.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Jan 22, 2015 11:04:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/chris@empatico.ca/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.1.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/clearbox/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.0.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/chris@empatico.ca/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.1.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/clearbox/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Anyone had an issue like this and if so, what can I do to resolve this seemingly random occurrence?

Comment: if i understand correctly eveything's ok in the normal mode ?
Sometimes too much breakpoints in eclipse leads to this sort of bug. I don"t know really why.

Comment: @vincent Yes when starting up tomcat normally it starts up without a hitch. It takes 30 seconds but outside of that it works fine.

Comment: You can increase the start timeout value. If your server is defined in STS, you should be able to see that in Servers tab. Double click --> Overview Window opens --> Expand Timeouts section --> Increase Start(In Seconds) to some bigger value say 800. Now that you've increased ur timeout, tomcat will not be shutdown forcefully until 800 seconds and you can check the logs in console if there's any other error/exception

Comment: @Arkantos Tried raising the timeout and it worked, but returned it to it's former value and ti also worked. It's almost like it healed itself.

Comment: just try to recall if u changed anything in ur app.. i doubt that java/tomcat is self healing ;)